# Why creating new Expo React Native App starts installing with Yarn?

Tags: npm, expo

I'm trying to install a new React Native Expo App and usually it installs with npm but now it starts installing with Yarn which I've never used. How can I make it install with npm again?

I know that an expo app can also be installed via yarn. But for school projects we are obliged to do via npm.
I tried npx create-expo-app my-app but it starts installing with Yarn

Answer (score 4):

`npx create-expo-app` will use Yarn if available as it's the most reliable solution for installing React Native packages. Use `npm create expo-app` to install with npm.

This can be found in the `--help` of `create-expo-app`:

```
    The package manager used for installing
    node modules is based on how you invoke the CLI:
    
     npm: npm create expo-app
    yarn: yarn create expo-app
    pnpm: pnpm create expo-app
```

Comment: It's not working.
npm create-expo-app my-app is not a npm comment you can use in PowerShell.

Also create a folder first and then npm i create-expo-app doesn't work.

Comment: @Gravaro_ I also had issues with `npm`. `yarn` and `react-native` both are developed by Facebook and thus you will often see the two used together.